# Physical meaning of the NV quantization axis

Tags: electrons, atoms

What is the physical meaning of the quantization axis (i.e. what is making this quantization axis exactly). I have yet to find resources that delve into it.

Comment: You choose it yourself when you make the measurement along that axis. Remember (this year's Nobel Prize!) that what you measure does not "exist". Only your measurement is meaningful: your choice, your "reality."

Comment: what is NV, and what is the context? Hydrogen atom, electron spin....

Comment: @mikestone how can we choose it ourselves when the NVs are in the fcc structure? It is clear that the quantization axes align with the fcc directions. But that is not really my question. The electrons are in orbitals and there are two unpaired electrons that make this "quantization axis". It is not clear to me how.

Comment: I’m not an expert in the field but I assume the line through the nitrogen and vacancy center in the lattice is often taken as the quantization axis.

Comment: What do fcc directions have to do with the quantization of spin?